# QR Code for TOTP multi factor (like google authenticator) -- how do I set my logo?

Tags: qr-code, google-authenticator, totp

We generate a QR code fine for TOTP multi factor. This QR code can be consumed fine by google authenticator, authy, etc.

We are trying to figure out how to include our logo, so the auth app can show our logo instead of a generic logo.

I have dug all over for the spec on what goes in the QR code, and have not found this info yet.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in [the spec](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/Key-Uri-Format) for adding a logo.

Instead, what services like Authy and [andOTP](https://github.com/andOTP/andOTP) do is look at the provider, and pattern match against a known list of popular providers.

For example, andOTP has [a curated list of thumbnails for specific services](https://github.com/andOTP/andOTP/wiki/Thumbnails).

If your organisation is as big as, say, Dropbox - you'll already be on the list. If not, you'll need to ask Authy and all the other providers to add your logo.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with TOTP at all. 
As the data in any QR code is redundant, there are some techniques allowing adding a logo by sacrificing the redundancy. Your QR code will become less readable though

https://hackaday.com/2011/08/11/how-to-put-your-logo-in-a-qr-code/

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not part of the spec, some implementations (at least FreeOTP) allows you to specify a logo with the `image` parameter.

example:

```
otpauth://totp/Issuer%3Ajohn%40example.com?image=https://picsum.photos/100&secret=4ED3SSHWSYSHC3FTEZFIOFPLDFIT2R2Y&issuer=Issuer
```

Not all implementations take this into account. In fact I only now for sure it works with [FreeOTP since 2014](https://github.com/freeotp/freeotp-android/commit/e1dbb3c6c3faf112a4bebb75057e0f739c52ac97). I've not digged further on other implementation.